# Visual Studio don't recognize system locale(double.Parse failed)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I faced with strange behavior of Visual Studio. I set USA locale for my computer and also for all users(before was RU). However double.Parse() works like delimiters is "," not ".". It's really confused me. I means that if I'm trying to parse like double.Parse( 0.006) it throw error, but 0,006 works great.

Thank you for help and advices.

Comment: Is it a desktop application? a web one? a windows service? Locale is specific to each user: be sure the user running your code (could be IIS_USR or Local_System) has the correct locale set

Comment: It's web-site. And it hosted on local IIS Server. Good idea to check. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [a Gian Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3276027/gian-paolo) replied that I had to change the locale for IIS Server, and it's helped me. I think it's happened because I had RU locale earlier. Thank you!